# Excel Table (If looking for "X" list what number it goes too and statment)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, worksheet

Here is my example:

```
                                                       RTU
                                                  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
Verify proper unit locations:                     X X X X √ √ √ √

Verify units marked for easy identification:      X √ √ √ X √ √ √
```

What I need is if any of the RTU's listed which in this case 8, if they are marked "X" I want it to tell me what RTU number (it does not have to say RTU, just a number is fine) and then reference the statement to the left.

So for example RTUs 1, 2, 3, and 4 have an X for "Verify proper units Locations" and RTU 1 and 5 have an X for "Verify Units marked for easy identification"

Is there a way that it can list:

1 "Verify Proper Units Locations"

2 "Verify Proper Units Locations"

3 "Verify Proper Units Locations"

4 "Verify Proper Units Locations"

1 "Verify Units marked for easy identification"

5 "Verify Units marked for easy identification"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the Scheme:

[image]

add the formula:

```
G6 -> =IF(G3="X";CONCATENATE(G2;" ""Verify Proper Units Locations""");"")
O6 -> =IF(G4="X";CONCATENATE(G2;" ""Verify Units marked for easy identification""");"")

G8 -> =IFERROR(INDEX(ResB;SMALL(IF(ResB<>"";COLUMN(ResB)-MIN(COLUMN(ResB))+1);ROW(K1)));"")
```

and autocomplete. The formila in G8 it's an array,than you need to insert with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.